# Python: IF statement consisting of data frame and list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis

I am very new to python and require help.
I have a list of keywords which was obtained from a data frame as follows:
`key_a_list = df_key_words['words'].tolist()`

I have a second data frame which consists of statements: `df_response['statement']`
I have already corrected spelling errors, tokenised and stemmed the text in the `df_response['statement']` column. 
I need to check if there are any words in the `key_a_list` that match words in the `df_response['statement']`; then I must set a counter to count the number of times a word from the `key_a_list` is present in the `df_response['statement']`.

Thank you for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated :)

This is the current code that I have but it gives me an error: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

```
count_a = 0
def count(x):
    for x in key_a_list:
        if key_a_list == df_response['statement']:
            count_a = count_a + 1      
    return count_a

df_response['statement'] = df_response['statement'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([count(x) for word in x.split()]))
```

the key_a_list consists of words like: ['think', 'college', 'education', 'help', 'better', 'prepare', 'career', 'chosen', 'eventually', 'enable', 'enter', 'job', 'market', 'field', 'like', 'make', 'choice', 'social', 'orientation', 'believe', 'additional', 'year', 'improve', 'competence', 'worker', 'prove', 'capable', 'completing', 'degree', 'rich', 'succeed', 'feel', 'important', 'show', 'intelligent', 'person', 'order', 'salary', 'later', 'on', 'want', 'the', 'good', 'life', 'study', 'highschool', 'actuary', 'find', 'highpaying', 'obtain', 'prestigious']

The df_response['statement'] looks as follows:

```
                  statement
0                  parent said
1         want make difference
2                    dont know
3                         rich
4               go career want
5                      actuary
6                  social life
7             expected society
```

where the desired output of df_response is:

```
                  statement         count_a
0                  parent said       0
1         want make difference       2
2                    dont know       0
3                         rich       1
4               go career want       2
5                      actuary       1
6                  social life       2
7             expected society       0
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help to see samples of your input dataframe and list, as well as your expected output, so that we could better understand your issue. See this link on creating a [mcve]

Comment: @G.Anderson, thank you for your suggestion! I have edited the question :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your output; you show `want make difference` as `0`, but your input list contains both `want` and `make`. Shouldn't that be a `2`?

Comment: My apologies @G.Anderson, it has been a long day looking at my computer. You are 100% correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to define your own function or use `apply()` here. Thankfully, pandas series have a handy built-in function: [series.str.count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html). Familiarizing yourself with the pandas `series.str...` methods can save you a ton of work! Just use the pipe character (`|`) to `join` your list to make it into a regex pattern, then `count` it

```
df['statement'].str.count('|'.join(key_a_list))

0    0
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    2
7    0

df['count_a']=df['statement'].str.count('|'.join(key_a_list))

df

    statement               count_a
0   parent said             0
1   want make difference    2
2   dont know               1
3   rich                    1
4   go career want          2
5   actuary                 1
6   social life             2
7   expected society        0
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me so much! I truly appreciate your time!

Comment: Glad I could help! [Here are the series.str docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-str), definitley worth keeping in the back of your mind. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the key_a_list in your if statement to "x" as x holds each word in key_a_list that the loop is iterating through. Next, you can use the keyword "in" to check if x is in df_response["statement"] and count up if it is.

Also, you can define count_a inside the function so it's not a global variable to avoid reset it each time you run the function count(x) instead of adding to the existing counter.

I think it should work this way, please more experienced members correct me if I'm wrong:

```
def count(x):
    count_a = 0
    for x in key_a_list:
        if x in df_response['statement']:
            count_a = count_a + 1      
    return count_a
```